# Why a subclass would override a base class method but make it identical (and not use it)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, python-unittest

Studying inheritance in Python, and my understanding so far is that a subclass only overwrites a method of the base class if it is intends for the method to do something different that of the base class.

So using [HowDoI](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi) as an example, we see that in test_howdoi.py the `HowdoiTestCase` class, which inherits from `unittest.TestCase`, overwrites `TestCase`'s `setUp()` function (which just `pass`es):

```
   def setUp(self):                                          
       self.queries = ['format date bash',                   
                       'print stack trace python',           
                       'convert mp4 to animated gif',        
                       'create tar archive']                 
       self.pt_queries = ['abrir arquivo em python',         
                          'enviar email em django',          
                          'hello world em c']                
       self.bad_queries = ['moe',                            
                           'mel']
```

OK so far.

test_howdoi.py then goes on though to overwrite `tearDown()`, yet it is written to just `pass` (as per the base class's definition). And tearDown() does not get used anywhere.

- Why would a base class function be overwritten with the same behaviour as its behavior in the base class?
- Why would it be overwritten at all if there is no intention to use it?

Comment: 1. I don't know, seems like either a waste of time or a misunderstanding. Maybe they just wanted a placeholder to show that it was there. 2. `tearDown` is called automatically on a `TestCase` when you run the tests.

Comment: Something is wrong with your pasted code.  It appears to be cut off at a certain column.

Comment: Guess: they used an IDE with the option of creating a stub `TestCase`, but they didn't need the `tearDown` method and left it as is.

Comment: @BrenBarn Fixed. Had no material implication for the question though.

Comment: I can think of only one case: the `child` is not supposed to possess functionality defined in the `parent`. This, however, completely defeats the purpose of defining that functionality in `parent`.

Comment: It _might_ run slightly faster as the method resolution method would find it sooner (but I can't imagine any case where the difference is enough to ever matter).  However, if speed was that much of an issue, I doubt that you'd want to write the code in pure python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure you're describing may be reduced to following code:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    # this declaration is redundant since exact same behaviour is already inherited.
    def f(self):  
        pass
```

And trying to answer your question:

> Why would it be overwritten at all if there is no intention to use it?

`setUp` and `tearDown` methods ARE used in unittest runners (as name suggests - before and after test).

> Why would a base class function be overwritten with the same behaviour
>   as its behavior in the base class?

Some of reasons may be:

- IDEs generated TestCase class stub, developer just kept it
- Developer didn't read docs, which states that `setUp` and `tearDown` are optional and have empty implementations by default
- Some developers like to explicitly write that setUp / tearDown is empty for current test suite

TLDR: By accident or due to personal preference.